# How to make changes of neo4j.conf take effect?

Tags: neo4j

```
$ neo4j version
neo4j 3.3.4
```

Host machine
https://neo4j.com/developer/neo4j-cloud-google-image/

Data Import

```
neo4j-admin import --database=actors.db --nodes movies.csv --nodes actors.csv --relationships roles.csv
```

after I changes to neo4j.conf as follows:

```
#dbms.active_database=graph.db

# changed into
dbms.active_database=actors.db
```

The server still points to graph.db.

I tried to restart the neo4j service to see if it will help

```
$ sudo service neo4j restart
```

However, neo4j.conf gets fully reset, and it is reverted back to

```
#dbms.active_database=graph.db
```

what is the proper step by step solution to change neo4j.conf?

Answer (score 3):

Can't comment because I don't have enough reputation points... but did you ever figure this out? I've been running into the same issue.

I overwrite the neo4j.conf file, but everytime I restart the service with:

```
$ sudo service neo4j restart
```

The neo4j.conf file goes back to how it was

---

**Update:** I was able to figure this out. Chances are you have a neo4j.template file which is used to create the neo4j.conf file each time the database is reset. If you edit that, you should be good to go.

Answer (score 2):

I also ran into same issue. When I dig more I found the answer. It is happening when I am trying to runNeo4J server on aws ec2 instance using custom community ami provided by Neo4j. There is a script having name pre-neo4j.sh which is configured to run on every restart of Neo4j service. Inside that script, it is replacing neo4j.conf on every restart of service with some configured template to preserve public-ip or anything like that.

[image]
[image]